# rails partial passing variable does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this:
view:

```
confirmations.each do |c|
  <%= render "form", confirmation: c %>
end
```

partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for @confirmation do |f| %>
    ...
```

Rails for some reason gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError in Rosters#show

undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass
```

highlighting the line in the above partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError in Rosters#show
>
> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

It should be `<%= simple_form_for confirmation do |f| %>` not `<%= simple_form_for @confirmation do |f| %>` as your variable is `confirmation` not `@confirmation`

Comment: In other files I have <%= render "form", confirmation: @c %> and it works

Comment: @DrevanTonder It all depends on existence or access of `@confirmation`. Does the error resolved?

Comment: @DrevanTonder Then you should accept my answer and BTW read more about local variables and instance variables in Ruby.

Comment: Stackoverflow was making me wait for a minute.